# how to get only .txt files to ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I have this code in my activity. With this code I get all files but I want to get only `.txt` files not all files. what can I do with `MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());`

```
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public void li () {
    ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles("/sdcard");
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));
    Collections.sort(FilesInFolder );
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, 
long id) {
        String s = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        h = s;
  //to do
            }
         }
    }); 
}

public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0)
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.foldeisempty, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
            MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
    }

    return MyFiles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn this:

```
for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
    MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
```

Into this:

```
string fileName="";
string extension="";
for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
    fileName=files[i].getName();
    extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    if(extension==".txt")MyFiles.add(fileName);
}
```

And make sure you have this at the top of the module, which makes "Path.GetExtension" available:

```
using System.IO
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm new so I do not understand "Path.GetExtension". Can you give example how am I use this? Thanks.

Comment: It takes the "extension" of a file (after the last dot in the filename) and returns it.

Path.GetExtension on "file.txt" returns ".txt".

Path.GetExtension on "file.txt.backup" returns ".backup".

Path.GetExtension on "c:/windows/explorer.exe" returns ".exe".

Comment: I got it. But I have one problem with "The method GetExtension(String) is undefined for the type Path" message. Could you help this. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure "using System.IO" is listed in your references at the top of the code module.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the file type

```
for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(files[i].getName());
    if (extension = '.txt')
        MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
}
```